# Better Way for Get PHP URI Action form

Tags: php, forms

I have Any Form for send data to mysql! now  What's Best, Secure , Optimized way for get action UrI.

One :

```
function url(){
  $protocol = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? "https" : "http";
  return $protocol . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}

<form action ="<?PHP echo url(); ?>" method="POST">
```

Two :

```
    $url = http://localhost/test

    <form action ="<?PHP echo $url. '/admin/edit.php' ?>" method="POST">
```

Three :

```
    $fol = '/test';
    define('PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $fol);

    echo ' <form action = "' . PATH . '/admin/edit.php" method="POST"> ';
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use a relative url as `<form>`s `action`.

Comment: As @Vague says, you can simple use `<form action="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="post">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option one is OK. Option two is the most secure, since it doesn't contain any user input. Three is impossible, since the document root isn't an HTTP path, but rather a local path on your webserver.

Comment: Yes ! I agree with you. My Choose Is : Two.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action ="" method="POST">
```

seems okay to me

Comment: This Worked Only For SELF Action!

Comment: Sure. Like your option one. If it is not what you want - why did you list it?

Comment: With this method you can add it as well.

Answer (score -1):

[PHP: Sql Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Refer things here. It explains the preventive measures for careful handling of data with mysql.

Comment: For This : Secured For Remote file inclusion OR Remote Url Injection ! ;)

Comment: what are your targets when you say secure & optimize? using normal urls preceded with baseUrl is very much in practice.

Answer (score -1):

FORM tag is in HTML, its *action* property is a url of php file on server to REQUEST. 
I think we cannot send data direct from FORM tag to MYSQL 
All of ways you use have a same result on browsers. 
To improve the Secure, you can use another method such as HTTPS for submit data.